# What are all the permission required other redshift query result to my AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam

We have access to other AWS redshift cluster. We want to unload one of the tables query results into our S3 bucket. Can we know what are all the permissions required to unload those results into our S3 bucket.

Tried to search in google but didn't find any related doc.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access a `Redshift`, any table/view and could do SELECT on it, then you should be able to `unload` that select as well. No special permissions are required as far as `Redshift` is concerned.

Though you need to have valid `S3` `IAM` `role` or `S3` `Access/Secret Key` to unload the data.
Other way to look into `unload` is, its more of selecting bulk data and redirecting it to a physical store S3 for other purposes.

Here is official `unload` documentation page.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html

**With S3 credentials**

```
unload ('select * from venue')  to 's3://mybucket/tickit/venue_' access_key_id <access-key-id>' secret_access_key '<secret-access-key>'
```

**With IAM Role,**

```
 unload ('select * from venue') to 's3://mybucket/tickit/unload/venue_' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';
```